# Merge files task AzureDevops

Tags: powershell, junit, azure-devops

Good morning

I am trying to merge two .xml files as a PowerShell task.

```
$testResultFiles = Get-ChildItem *.postman_collection.xml

dir

$filesNames = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]

foreach($file in $testResultFiles)
{
        Write-Host $file.FullName

       $filesNames.Add($file.Name)
}

Write-Host junit-merge $filesNames 

junit-merge $filesNames
```

I get an exception:

> Error: File not found
>       at getTestsuites (C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\junit-merge\lib\index.js:82:11)
>       at C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\junit-merge\lib\index.js:112:17

The message is about no files found. However I see as an output using

> dir

that those files exists

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue that you are adding the file **Name** and not the whole path and file name e.g. **FullName**?

i.e. your original code:

```
Write-Host $file.FullName

$filesNames.Add($file.Name)
```

This code, although it displays the whole path, you are only adding the File Name to the list. Therefore when junit-merge runs, it will run from the current location, and not the full path as expected.

So should it be:

```
Write-Host $file.FullName

$filesNames.Add($file.FullName)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Another thought might be that it is that the `$fileNames` object is being passed in and interpreted as a single string argument rather than a proper "space separated" argument list, which is interpreted as an argument array.

We can use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) to manually "unroll" the `List` into something that will be interpreted as separate arguments by using the `@` sign.

```
junit-merge @filesNames
```

Comment: Didnt help but why should it help ? This task is in the same directory as these files

Comment: Ah, I think that it's interpreting the Arguments as a single long string, instead of separate arguments. See my edits above.